# Probability of Seeing People on a Trail

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I went hiking this weekend (a there-and-back trail) and noticed that I saw people more frequently as I neared the end of the trail (the half-way mark.) Whenever I exited the car there were less people coming and going, and as I hiked toward the turnaround point, more and more people appeared coming in my oppsite direction.

Once I reached the turnaround point, this processed reversed: I started walking and the people-traffic was heavy. As I neared my car, the poplulation had dispersed and it seemed to be only me around.

My question is this: is their any function that explains the probability distribution of hikers on a there-and-back trail?

Comment: Maybe you chose a popular time to start your hike.  Suppose every hiker on a particular day starts from the trailhead at a distinct time, but within a window of 10 minutes and walks at the same constant speed.  No hiker meets anybody else unless (s)he is within 5 minutes from the far end of the trail.

Comment: Any PDF whose weight increases towards the center (normal distribution for example) would explain what you report. The center would be the turnaround point. That prompts the question: why would hikers tend to cluster in the center? A few possibilities: 1) no reason, it's just happened to be that way during your hike 2)  you started after a cluster of people did - that cluster became dispersed due to speed differences and you catch up to slow side of cluster before center 3) people slow down near the center or stop at the center (speed is in some respects proportional to distance from center)